# Monitor Internet traffic flowing via my MacBook?

Tags: network, wifi, internet-sharing

My MacBook is connected to an Internet cable and meanwhile sharing the Internet connection with other devices over Wi-Fi. That is, my MacBook serves as a router, which broadcasts Wi-Fi signals.

Since essentially, all the Internet packets travel through my MacBook, there must be a way whereby I can monitor which device is viewing what contents using my hot spot.

Is there a software (preferably free) or some built-in block that allows me to achieve this?

Comment: **To downvoters: indicate your reasons, please.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark). This has a GUI to allow you to specify all sorts of filters, even down to the ports/protocols being used - or by MAC address or IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the terminal command `tcpdump` as it will show all the traffic passing over your network. You have to run it via sudo but it should give you what you want.

```
sudo tcpdump -vv -i en0
```

Should show everything over your ethernet port.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really shows me a lot, but maybe too much. Is it possible to just show "skimmed" info.? Like, which MAC address visits which IP address. That would suffice for me. e.g., Device1'sMACAddress 124.63.24.1

Comment: Take a look at the man page for it there are a fair number of flags that can change what information is being delivered. Or pipe it through a sed to grab the info you are looking for

Comment: also there are some tools to help...  http://www.zdnet.com/making-sense-of-tcpdump-with-add-on-enhancements-2039050816/